# Python Selenium execute_script("return window.dataLayer") returns stale reference? What's stale? It's all still there

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, staleelementreferenceexception

I can watch `execute_script()` run many many times in the AngularJS routed single page I'm testing since it seems a lot of the code uses `execute_script()` to talk to the browser.

The specific call is:

```
driver.execute_script("return window.dataLayer")
```

Which works many times successfully.

But at some point, that same command receives a 404 from Selenium.  I dug into the python selenium:

Deep in urllib3 it's POSTing this same as every other time:

```
ipdb> urlopen_kw                                                                                                
{'body': '{"script": "return window.dataLayer", "args": []}', 'request_url': 'http://127.0.0.1:51673/session/<sessionidxxx>/execute/sync'}
```

But at the same place in the test, suddenly the response from the request is:

```
ipdb> data
'{"value":{"error":"stale element reference","message":"stale element reference: stale element not found\\n  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)","stacktrace":"#0 0x561877802d99 \\u003C
unknown>\\n"}}'
```

I'm on Ubuntu:

```
/usr/bin❯ chromium-browser --version
Using PPAPI flash.
Chromium 84.0.4147.105 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04

/usr/bin❯ chromedriver --version    
ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30
```

That ChromeDriver was found via: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection

Using pdb, I'm still perfectly able to use `execute_script(<command>)` to interact with the page and everything on it.  And the URL isn't changing and the page is not refreshing.

It just seems that somehow the specific `window.dataLayer` (while still present and complete in the browser dev console) is "stale".  Is it cached somewhere? In the webdriver? Is there a way to stop that?

The only connection I can make is that when I only used the dataLayer object for one evaluation it seems to NOT break.  But I enhanced the code to look at the dataLayer in a loop (after acquiring it once).  It would not immediately go stale. But after a larger interaction triggering XHR and other requests, suddenly it says it's stale.  Very confusing.

I hope this is enough information for somebody to recognize what might be the cause.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

As you are looping through elements while performing some actions on them. Its look like your page is getting refreshed. As a result either elements you have stored earlier are either getting reloaded or lost altogether. One of technique of overcoming stale element is loop is, for every iteration use a fresh locator for your element and access it with the help of iteration number of your loop.

Comment: Share the HTML DOM of your elements, so that i can try in my local.

Comment: Thanks!  In this case it's not a DOM element, it's a property on the window object itself.  If I pause execution.  The `window.dataLayer` is still present and populated as I can still inspect it from the browser directly.  Also, when it fails, it happens immediately, not during the looping.  But you are making me think somehow I need to isolate this by reducing the steps of the test and the complexity of the page until I can get it to work!